# How to optimize insert from select in For loop in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, loops

I am trying to compute cash balances bunch of tables and insert them into another table.  I have a loop which computes the balance for each date of the year and inserts it into the balance table.

The problem is that this sql takes almost half an hour:

```
declare
    d_i number :=1
begin
    loop
        insert into my_cash_table
        select 
               portfolio , 
               book_name, position_type, currency, cash_balance_cad
        from 
               cash_balance cb
               -- plus bunch of code here
               ...
        where  bal_date in &sdate + d_i
        group by book_name, position_type, currency;

        d_i := d_i + 1;   

        if d_i > 366 then
            exit;
        end if;
    end loop;
end;
```

Is there anyway for me to optimize it so that I can grab all the data in a loop and then just bulk insert?  Also can I run simply select statement in a loop, i.e. without doing an insert?

Thank you

Comment: You can almost certainly write a single SQL statement that inserts data for the entire year rather than iterating through a loop at all.  You haven't really shown us enough to be able to write such a SQL statement, though.  Your `insert` statement, for example, isn't inserting a date.  It's doing a `group by` but not doing any aggregation, etc.  If you put together a small reproducible test case and add that to your question, we can probably help.

Comment: Thanks!  That lit a light bulb in my head.  However I still want to understand if there is a better way to loop than insert a select multiple times and if there is a way to simply select using a loop without inserting.

Comment: You can select data in a loop but you'd have to put the data you're selecting somewhere.  If you're not inserting it into a table you could put the data in a local collection.  I'm hard-pressed to see how that would help you in this instance but you could certainly do it.  If you want to loop through the days rather than doing a single `insert` statement, I'm not sure what "better" would mean in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need optimization of your query.
In order to exclude context switching between sql and plsql you may go two ways.

1. Use subquery or with statement to generate numbers from 1 to 366 and multiply inserting rows by joining to it:

   ```
    begin
      insert into my_cash_table
        with days_num_q as
         (select level num 
            from dual 
         connect by level <= 366)
        select portfolio,
               book_name,
               position_type,
               currency,
               cash_balance_cad
          from cash_balance cb
          join cnt_days  
            on bal_date = &sdate + days_num_q.num
        /*  -- plus bunch of code here
          .....
        */;
    end;
   ```
2. Create nested collection of numbers from 1 to 366 and use forall statement:

   ```
    declare
      type days_num_tbl_type is table of number;
      days_num_tbl           days_num_tbl_type;
      d_i                    number;
    begin
      d_i := 1:
      days_num_tbl := days_num_tbl_type();
      days_num_tbl.extend(366);

      while d_i <= 366 loop
        days_num_tbl(d_i) := d_i;
        d_i := d_i + 1;
      end loop;

      forall i in days_num_tbl.FIRST..days_num_tbl.LAST
        insert into my_cash_table
        select portfolio,
               book_name,
               position_type,
               currency,
               cash_balance_cad
          from cash_balance cb
         /*  -- plus bunch of code here
          .....
        */
         where bal_date = &sdate + days_num_tbl(i);
    end;
   ```